# How to listen for events from the a class and its subclasses in a simple way in YUI3?

Tags: yui

I have a YUI widget 'Container' that contains widgets that subclass 'Content', in the Content class, i have :

```
Y.mynamespace.Content = Y.Base.create('content', Y.Widget, [],{

     initializer : function(){
       this.publish('select');
}

//..... the rest
})
```

so every subclass of Content can fire a 'select' event. Now I want my 'Container' widget to catch the 'select' event from all subclasses of Content by adding itself as the event target (content.addTarget()), however, to add an event listen, I have to add for every subclass of Content like :

```
this.on('content-subclass1:select',fn);
this.on('content-subclass2:select',fn);
this.on('content-subclass3:select',fn);
```

What I want is something like :

```
this.on('child:select',fn);
```

Is it possible? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `*` as a wildcard for all subclasses: `this.on('*:select', fn)`.